# Unitarity/Hermiticity condition for $osp(m,n|\mathbb{C})$ superalgebra

Tags: string-theory, group-theory, supersymmetry, representation-theory, superalgebra

According to [Dictionary on Lie Superalgebras](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9607161.pdf) (page 82), the compact form of $OSP(m,n|\mathbb C)$ Lie superalgebra must satisfy $M^{\text st}H\,M=1$ and $M^{\ddagger}M=1$ (is this the unitarity condition?), this means that the conditions for the corresponding superalgebra are $E^{\text st}H+HE=0$ and $E^{\ddagger}+E=0$ (right? it could be $E^{\ddagger}-E=0$?) due to the exponential map. So $E$ must be anti-Hermitian (right?, see [Reduced matrix elements of the orthosymplectic Lie superalgebra](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.7142.pdf) (page 32) in which it looks that this condition needs to be applied "by blocks"). Here, $$H=\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbb{I}_m & 0\\ 
0 & \mathbb{J}_{2p}
\end{pmatrix},\quad \mathbb{J}_{2p}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \mathbb{I}_p\\ 
-\mathbb{I}_p & 0
\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}$$

and $E=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B\\ 
C & D
\end{pmatrix}$ is an even supermatrix, so $A$ and $D$ are bosonic, and $B$ and $C$ are fermionic. The supertranspose operation is

$$E^{\text st}=\begin{pmatrix}
A^{\text t} & C^{\text t}\\ 
-B^{\text t} & D^{\text t}
\end{pmatrix}\tag{2}$$

as defined in page 84 of ([1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9607161.pdf)). By imposing

$$E^{\text st}H+HE=0 \tag{3}$$

I get the usual conditions for the $SO(m)\times Sp(n)$ bosonic subalgebra, and others for the fermionic part.

My problem is with the operation $\ddagger$. According to ([1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9607161.pdf)) (page 84) (see also [Graded Lie algebras: Generalization of Hermitian representations](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.523148) ),

$$E^{\ddagger}=(E^{\text st})^\#$$

The $\#$ operation is a "superconjugation" or superstar. It is not clearly expressed in ([1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9607161.pdf)) so I went to [CURRENT SUPERALGEBRAS AND UNITARY REPRESENTATIONS](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.00282.pdf) (page 18) in which $\#$ is defined as

$$E^{\#}=\begin{pmatrix}
A^{*} & -iC^{*}\\ 
-iB^{*} & D^{*}
\end{pmatrix}\tag{4}$$

involving usual conjugation and a transpose!(does this agree with the definitions in ([1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9607161.pdf)) and ([5](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=35F3317B20C8B7B52DDB054C06EFA64C))). So it looks like $\#$ is already something like $\ddagger$. With this, a unitary representation of $\mathscr{gl}(m,n|\mathbb C)$, according to ([4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.00282.pdf)) must satisfy $E^{\#}+E=0$  from which $C=iB^{*}$. this operation is given also in [Cornwell's Group theory in physics, vol. 3](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=35F3317B20C8B7B52DDB054C06EFA64C) (page 11) but it is not so clear for me.

At the end, $-E=E^{\ddagger}:=(E^{\text st})^\#=-E^{\text st}\Rightarrow E=E^{\text st}?$ and from the condition of $OSP$, $E=-HEH^{-1}$? So this condition with $E^{\text st}H+HE=0$ allows to get the unitary $osp$ superalgebra?

Notice also [Superstrings on AdS4 × CP3 as a Coset Sigma-model](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.4940.pdf) (page 5) in which eq. (2.4) corresponds to the hermiticity (unitarity) condition.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v1): In the future please link to abstract pages rather than pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently $E^{\#}\equiv E^{\ddagger}$ and $*\equiv\dagger$, so the condition $$E^{\#}=-E\tag{1}$$
for unitarity, is the same as $$E^{\ddagger}=-E \tag{2}$$
That's why you have a transpose in the definition of $E^{\#}$! SO, actually $C=-iB^{\dagger}$. And, with $E^{\text{st}}H+HE=0$, you get the generators of $uosp(m,n|\mathbb C)$.

In order to "unify" definitions, this is what happens

$$E^{\ddagger}:=(E^{\text{st}})^{\#}:=\begin{pmatrix}
A^t & C^t\\ 
-B^t & D^t
\end{pmatrix}^{\#}=\begin{pmatrix}
A^{t*} & -iC^{t*}\\ 
-iB^{t*} & D^{t*}
\end{pmatrix}=-E \tag{3}$$